# How can i delete a row regarding of which a trigger is invoked, by the trigger itself?

Tags: database, oracle

my problem is as follows,
firstly here is my code,

```
create or replace trigger tri_ISSUE
after insert or delete
on ISSUE
for each row
declare
    ct varchar2(20);
    cnt number(20);
begin
    if inserting
    then
        select bk_category into ct from BOOK_MASTER where accn_no=:new.accn_no;
        select available into cnt from BOOK_INFO where bk_category=ct;
        if(cnt=0)
        then
            dbms_output.put_line('Book is not available!');
            delete ISSUE where rollno=:new.rollno and accn_no=:new.accn_no;
        else
            select bk_category into ct from BOOK_MASTER where accn_no=:new.accn_no;
            update BOOK_INFO set available=available-1 where bk_category=ct;
        end if;
    end if;
    if deleting
    then
        select bk_category into ct from BOOK_MASTER where accn_no=:old.accn_no;
        update BOOK_INFO set available=available+1 where bk_category=ct;
    end if;
end;
```

I am getting an error like this,

```
ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.ISSUE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.TRI_ISSUE", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.TRI_ISSUE'
```

what i am trying to do is, i want to delete the row which is being inserted, by a 'After Insert' trigger which is invoked followed by the insertion. Can i actually do that? can anyone suggest me a remedy? thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, you can't.  You could raise an exception to prevent the `insert` from succeeding.  You could (depending on Oracle version) have a compound trigger with a before statement, row-level, and after statement section where you do the delete in the after statement portion of the trigger.  That adds a great deal of complexity to the system.  Why do you want to put this logic in a trigger in the first place rather than having the code that implements a check-out validate that the book is actually available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your requirements.

1. Put all your logic into a procedure. This is most likely the best way of doing it.
2. Replace line `delete ISSUE where rollno = :new.rollno and accn_no = :new.accn_no;` by `raise_application_error(-20001, 'Book is not available!');`

   With this the user gets an exception and data is not inserted.
3. Create a [compound trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CIHEFGFD) with `BEFORE STATEMENT`, `BEFORE EACH ROW` and `AFTER STATEMENT` component.
4. Create a view and an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`, would be like this:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_ISSUE AS 
   SELECT * FROM ISSUE;

   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_ISSUE
     INSTEAD OF INSERT OR DELETE ON V_ISSUE
     FOR EACH ROW

   declare
       ct varchar2(20);
       cnt number(20);
   begin
       if inserting
       then
           select bk_category into ct from BOOK_MASTER where accn_no=:new.accn_no;
           select available into cnt from BOOK_INFO where bk_category=ct;
           if(cnt=0)
           then
               dbms_output.put_line('Book is not available!');
               NULL; -- > do nothing
           else
               INSERT INTO ISSUE VALUES (... all coloums of this table);
               select bk_category into ct from BOOK_MASTER where accn_no=:new.accn_no;
               update BOOK_INFO set available=available-1 where bk_category=ct;
           end if;
       end if;
       if deleting
       then
           DELETE FROM ISSUE WHERE ...;
           select bk_category into ct from BOOK_MASTER where accn_no=:old.accn_no;
           update BOOK_INFO set available=available+1 where bk_category=ct;
       end if;
   END;
   ```